# Create a new site from a template

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sub-site, template

I have read a lots of posts, did a lots of google search but none of the solutions are working for me. I am trying to create a subsite from a template. Tried both GUI and powershell. I keep getting this error when using powershell.

> exception calling applywebtemplate with 1 argument(s) file or argument
>   not valid for site template

Can anyone please help on how to troubleshoot this issue?
Thanks

Comment: Looks like you have a webapplication/farm that's malfunctioning. What version are you using? Any custom solutions embedded in the template? One way to try is to create a new web app, a new site collection, and a new subsite and see if you have the same errors there. If you do, there must be something else showing in the ULS or Event Viewer...

Comment: @dkorra as Benny Skogberg said if you check the logs with the correlation  id shown below error msg then you will get some clue about actual problem.

Comment: is it a custom template or OOTB? if custom how you created and deployed in farm?

Comment: its a custom template @WaqasSarwarMCSE,  so I already have the site as a template and wanted to use it to create other sites.

Answer (score 1):

First:

- Create a subsite, which you will use as template.
- Edit the template to fit your needs
- Site Settings > Site Action > Save site as template (or use URL below)
- http://SiteCollectionURL/My-Subsite-Template/_layouts/15/savetmpl.aspx

Second:

- Browse to site content and add new subsite
- Select custom tab, and find your template there
  [image]

Beware though, the link "save as site tempalte" isn't visible if you have publishing feature switched on. But usually using the URL won't get you into trouble even if it's not oficially supported by Microsoft.

Comment: Yes I did all that, but then it will give an error saying, can not complete action. nothing relevant when checking with coorelation id.

Comment: @dkorra it is giving error while saving site as template or while creating site from template?

Comment: error is while creating the site from template. @RaghavendraC